# Dynamic animation using mic volume as trigger

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I am new to iPhone development, and I am looking for someone with experience
to simply tell me whether I am on the right path or to perhaps point me to it
regarding what I am trying to acheive.

I am trying to develop a character animation that reacts to the volume of
the microphone input.  Something like Talking Tomcat, except that instead of
having just a face react to the volume, an entire character´s body is involved.

The character has been created in illustrator and it is image based.  So
this will be a 2D animation.  I have created numerous frames for the different
kinds of reactions the character will have depending on the volume.

For my animation I am using `UIViews` using its Animation resources and adding
`UIImageViews` as subviews. I am also using `CGAffineTransforms` for rotating
images.
   I am also relying on Timers to control the different stages of the
animation.

To allow for a more flexible animation, I have created `UIViews` for the head,
arms, torso and legs of the character.  These have been severed into their own
images and I am manipulating these images individually through UIViews.

I can go over my code in more detail if necessary, although any help will be greatly appreciated even if it is something off the bat.

Comment: add some objective-c, cocoa touch tags to your question, this will help ;)

Comment: Where is the programming question here?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am new to StackOverflow as well.  Thank you for the tags.
Perhaps it's has more to do with conceptualization than programming.
But only an experienced iOS programmer is able to answer my question. 
Would you resort to using the Animation resources of UIViews and CGAffineTransform in order to create character animation based on images, or is there a better way to go about it.  What would you use to create a 2d character animation?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you're not an advanced ios developer I would suggest starting with cocos2d.
It has everything you need to start with animation.
Web page and forums has plenty of information on how to do it and... what's most important [to me at least], you've got gurus like Ray Wenderlich writing excellent tutorials like:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d

Comment: Thank you Krystian.  I had already bumped into that site a while ago. Great resource.